# How to remove pyridine from Reaction mixture containing chiral molecule with diacetal protection group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, purification

While working with chiral molecule, we have pyridine in our reaction mixture. Molecule has four chiral centre and protection group-diacetal and acetyl groups which may break in harsh conditions. Please suggest work up methods to remove pyridine.

Comment: Please, provide name/structure of the compound. As a general idea, I think pyridine might be evaporated given enough time, but it definitely is not fast or easy.

Comment: Aquaeous extraction with a saturated ammonium chloride solution is usually the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Extract the organic soln of the product with dilute aq. Cu(II) until the characteristic blue of the Cu-pyridine complex is absent from the aq. phase.